# Is there an android application which would watch my app and let me know if I'm leaving things running?

Tags: android, performance

I'm working on an android application which registers with various sensors. I am doing my best to ensure that the application unregisters every time it's paused, but I'd love to have an application which would watch it and tell me if it's still using battery in the background when the application is supposed to be paused.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: Not related to sensors, but still nice to know: [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) - there is also a [introduction](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html) in the android developers blog.